# Spring 4 MVC | using Jackson binding to return Json with xml based configuration

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-4

Spring 4 MVC based project with xml based configuration, want to use Jackson binding to return Json for some of the controller mappings (and it's going to Google App Engine).
Did a lot of investigating, many different solution but they doing, each one, a bit different approach then the one we have. No yet working solution.

**web.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config/application-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Spring **application-context.xml**:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd ">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.wixpress.automation"/>

        <bean id="viewResolver"
              class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix">
                <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
            </property>
            <property name="suffix">
                <value>.jsp</value>
            </property>
        </bean>     
    </beans>
```

My example **controller** is pretty slim:

```
@Controller 
@RequestMapping("/api/")
public class Controller {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/name", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Name nameexample(WebRequest request, Model model) {
        final Name name = new Name("name", "class", "package");
        return name;
    }
}
```

The **class Name** is a simple POJO with getters/setters, implements Serializable.

**pom.xml** got all the Jackson dependencies: jackson-databind, jackson-core, jackson-annotations, version 2.6.0. Spring used: 4.2.0.RELEASE

The **error** I receive when trying to GET the url:
*org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation*

Comment: So, what do you do, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: @JBNizet expect to receive the JSON representation of the object (got other url mapping that returns VIEWs, they work). Adding all the other relevant info to the q. Please tell me if something missing.

Comment: What is the value of your Accept request header?

Comment: @JBNizet Accept: application/json

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it's the same as using ResponseBody + Controller together, the same as I have.